# run multiple function selects postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to run a remove_user function 1000s of times in single postgres query with a different values. I have created the statements.

Currently If I select all still only executes first line. I am using PGadmin.

```
SELECT public.remove_user(56);
SELECT public.remove_user(57);
SELECT public.remove_user(58);
SELECT public.remove_user(59);
SELECT public.remove_user(60);
SELECT public.remove_user(61);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds more like a pgAdmin problem, than a Postgres problem.

But if pgAdmin can't run set of statements, then you can rewrite that to a single statement:

```
select public.remove_user(id)
from ( 
   values (56), (57), (58), (59), (60), (61)
) as x(id);
```

Comment: Agreed this should of worked but your solution worked well now RSI adverted